# Deactivate pushKit in foreground

Tags: ios, swift, push, voip, pushkit

My app receives pushKit for VOiP calls but when it is in foreground calls have it's own incoming call view so I don't want to show callKit every time when app receive a new VOiP, just only when is in background or inactive. But far as I know a pushKit rules say is mandatory to show callKit in:

```
pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        Logger.debug("didReceiveIncomingPushWith", payload.dictionaryPayload.debugDescription)
```

Or get banned from APNS.

So it's posible to deactivate pushKit when app is running in foreground?

My code use:

```
var voipRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: nil)
voipRegistry.delegate = self
voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushType.voIP]
```

To activate pushKit, but looks like `PKPushRegistry` doesn't have any method to control it's behaviour

Comment: You must report the incoming call, but if your app is in the foreground you can immediately report the  incoming call as cancelled to callkit and then present your own screen

Comment: @Paulw11 cancel the call in callKit immediately would not ban my app from APNS?

Comment: No. As long as you report an incoming call in response to a PushKit notification you have satisfied the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The changes introduced by Apple to handle VOIP calls really breaks the usual way of handling VOIP calls.
Please refer to this official answer from Apple https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/117939, I'm sure this will help you understand what you can and cannot do with VOIP call, VOIP Push notifications and CallKit.

Comment: This works for me, it's really annoying how Apple decide to implement PushKit, really breaks the VoIP connection flow